# DropBox Core API in C#/Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, dropbox-api

I'm making a mobile application for iPhone using Xamarin where I want my user to authorize them to DropBox folder. I learned that there are several C# libraries used for DropBox integration. But everything (DropNet, DropboxRestAPI etc) seems to have been built for integrating into the web applications and not in the mobile applications.
Here is what I'm trying to achieve.
1. Authorize DropBox using the dropbox application installed on the phone and not by launching the browser in the mobile app
2. Get the request token
3. Exchange the request token into access token

The components available for xamarin are built on sync API. Is there any dropbox core API available in C# for achieving the above said?

Comment: Cross-linking with the Dropbox API forum: https://www.dropboxforum.com/hc/communities/public/questions/202351129-DropBox-Core-API-mobile-platform-in-C-

Answer (score 1):

Core API is available by now on Xamarin.
[Xamarin iOS](https://components.xamarin.com/view/dropboxcoreapiios) since July 2015, [Xamarin Droid](https://components.xamarin.com/view/dropboxcoreapiandroid) since January 2016.

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin have their [own component for Dropbox](http://components.xamarin.com/view/dropboxsync/), however this makes use of the Sync API which has since [been deprecated](http://blogs.dropbox.com/developers/2015/04/deprecating-the-sync-and-datastore-apis/) in favor of their updated Core API.

Based on their documentation it states that applications using the Sync API will continue to work as that is built on top of the Core API, however Dropbox will no longer distribute further updates for it.

It is strongly recommended that you move to adopt the [Core API](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core), however looking at their documentation page there doesn't appear to be a specific SDK for C#/Xamarin at this time.